# Excel creating additional sheets by copying but keeping formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have a workbook (we are using them for electronic purchase orders) and I need to be able to copy a worksheet but have the formula in it increment like it would if I copied the formula in a sheet.

In other words in sheet2 I1 the formula is ='Sheet1'!$I$1+1. When I copy sheet2 and it becomes sheet3, I need the formula in I1 to say ='Sheet2'!$I$1+1.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a string containing the current sheet name with the following formula

```
=cell("filename",A1)
```

If you are using the standard Sheet# for your pages, then you can get the current sheet number with this formula (assuming the previous one was in B3)

```
=RIGHT(B3,LEN(B3) - FIND("]Sheet",B3,1)-5)
```

Next calculate the number for the previous sheet

```
=VALUE(B4)+1
```

Now you can use the indirect function to address a cell in the previous sheet

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet"&B5&"!B1")
```

In Sheet4, this will reference B1 in Sheet3.
Copy it to Sheet5 and it will reference B1 in Sheet 4.